# How rjava function? how pass value to and from Java/R

Tags: java, r, jakarta-ee, rjava

I am a Java and **R** beginner. My task is very simple. I want to put a value from Java to **R**. Then in **R**, sum the input value with one and pass the back to Java and display the value.

How? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[JRI](http://rosuda.org/JRI/) is a good place to start.  It provides the ability to run R inside of a java program.      Once you have it downloaded you'll want to read the README as it gives installation instructions.  There are some examples in the /examples folder provide with JRI that walk you through the creation of the R Engine and shows you how to do some simple tasks.  I've never personally used it but this looks to be like what you're looking for.

Comment: i do not want run R inside the java program ( because java does not have some library i use in R). Other way, is it possible i call my .R file from java ? then the R file will execute.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it more clear what you want to do?

Comment: can java import and use the the svm or kernlab package? I has the svm and DWT code that write in R. But i use java to read the tablet, get the x and y coordinates and do some interface. The problem is how i can integrate java and R?

Comment: I still think that JRI is the way to go by the way.  You basically get an R session within Java using this.